# DependencyProperty doesn't fire ValueChanged when new value is the same

Tags: wpf, callback, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

Ok so here's the problem: I wrote a UserControl which receives a new value say like every 100ms and does something with it. It has to handle each new value setter, even if the value didn't change. The UserControl has a few DependencyProperties:

```
public double CurrentValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CurrentValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentValueProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentValue", typeof(double), typeof(GraphControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));
```

In the XAML where this control is used, I just set the `Binding` of CurrentValue to a (INotifyPropertyChanged-enabled) property:

```
<uc:UserControl CurrentValue="{Binding MyValue}" ... />
```

viewmodel:

```
    public double MyValue
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            //if (_value == value) return;
            _value= value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyValue"));
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I explicitly commented out the `if equals then return` so it will fire the PropertyChanged event even when the value gets updated to the same value.

Now back to my user control, I tried registering the ValueChanged in two ways; first by using the `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`:

```
var propertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(CurrentValueProperty, typeof(GraphControl));
propertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(this, OnCurrentValueChanged);
```

or by using the `UIPropertyMetaData`:

```
new UIPropertyMetadata(0d, OnCurrentValueChangedCallback)
```

so a stub of the callback would look like:

```
private void Callback(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //do stuff
}
```

Ok now the problem is, the callback is not fired when the value doesn't explicitly change. I checked, and the `PropertyChanged` event is firing in my viewmodel, but the control doesn't see the change. When the value changes to a new value, it will handle the callback as expected.
Is there any way to override this behavior so that my callback method will always get hit?

**EDIT:**
I also tried using the `CoerceValueCallback`, and that one is hit when the value stays the same, but it doesn't help me with my problem I think...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your value up in an object, i.e. create a class to hold it - then set the property to a new instance of that class containing the new value, every time.  That means you're creating ~10 objects per second, but they are each different, will trigger the change event, and are only small (will be GC'd anyway). :)

Comment: Aah off course, something soo simple, why didn't I think of that! :-) It works perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to switch the value temporarily to something else then restore the previous one. You can do this entire trick transparently in the Coerce callback as such:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Test", typeof(object), typeof(School),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, TestChangedCallback, TestCoerceCallback));

static object TestCoerceCallback(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    if (baseValue != null && (d.GetValue(TestProperty) == baseValue))
    {
        d.SetCurrentValue(TestProperty, null);
        d.SetCurrentValue(TestProperty, baseValue);
    }
    return baseValue;
}
```

Just make sure your property code can handle the `null` value case gracefully.