# Dependency Property Equality Check

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I apologize if the title is a bit misleading didn't know how to word it.

My question is when does DependencyProperty performs its equality check and can you intercept it?

I have a Property called ExposedObject on my ViewModel, and ExposedBinding DependencyProperty on my UserControl

ViewModel:

```
public MyObject ExposedObject
{ 
    get { return _ExposedObject; }
    set 
    { 
         _ExposedObject = value; 
         OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

UserControl:

```
private static readonly DepedencyProperty ExposedBindingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(..., ...(null, PropertyChangedCallback));
```

Now I call the setter on ExposedObject setting it to itself (just to get the behaviour I want) hence calling OnPropertyChanged(), this does indeed cause getter on ExposedObject to be called. However my DependencyPropertys' PropertyChangedCallback doesn't fire (as expected, being that it is the same object), however what I would like to know is that is there away to detect a value being pushed along the binding? And respond appropriately when I need to even if the value stored on the DependencyProperty is the same as the object being pushed?

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826914/dependencyproperty-doesnt-fire-valuechanged-when-new-value-is-the-same)?

Comment: I saw that before :) It is on my list of possible fixes but I was wander if there might be away I wouldn't have to worry about wrapping it :)