# How to fire Property Changed Event when it's not actually changing

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, viewmodel

so I have a model which contains 2 variables, a List and a DateTime. In my UserControl I have a DependencyProperty and I also defined a PropertyChangedCallback.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("My", typeof(List<MyContainer>), typeof(UC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMyProperty)));

public List<MyContainer> My
{
    get
    {
        return GetValue(MyProperty) as List<MyContainer>;
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MyProperty, value);
    }
}
private static void OnMyProperty(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UC control = d as UC;
    //do stuff
}
```

On my form there is a button, which do the changes on the other model variable (on the DateTime).

```
private void Date_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyModel model = DataContext as MyModel;
    if (model != null)
    {
        model.Date = model.Date.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

And finally here is my model.

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<MyContainer> _My;
    private DateTime _Date;

    public MyModel()
    {
        _Date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        _My = new List<MyContainer>();
    }

    public List<MyContainer> My
    {
        get
        {
            return _My;
        }
        set
        {
            _My = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("My");
        }
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _Date;
        }
        set
        {
            _Date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Date");
            OnPropertyChanged("My");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

XAML declaration is the following.

```
<local:UC My="{Binding My}" />
```

So my problem is the after I hit the run, it fires the OnMyProperty once, after that if I hit the button, it changes the DateTime property well, but the OnMyProperty callback doesn't firing again. However I noticed that if I modify my model like this

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get
    {
       return _Date;
    }
    set
    {
        _Date = value;
        _My = new List<MyContainer>(_My); //added
        OnPropertyChanged("Date");
        OnPropertyChanged("My");
    }
}
```

now it fires it every time when I hit the button. How can I trigger the second behaviour without that modification?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DependencyProperty doesn't fire ValueChanged when new value is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826914/dependencyproperty-doesnt-fire-valuechanged-when-new-value-is-the-same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you almost certainly do not need to do this. When you ask a question about how to make the framework do something it really does not want to do, always say *why you think you need to do that*. It's very likely that there's a much easier answer that everybody else is already using.

The only thing you have bound to the control is `My`. Therefore, if `My` hasn't changed, then the state of the control should not change. If you want the state of the control to change when `Date` changes, bind `Date` to some property of the control. The *only* way the control should ever get information from any viewmodel is through binding one of its dependency properties to a property of the viewmodel.

The control should not ever know or care who or what is providing values for its properties. It should be able to do its job knowing only the property values it has been given.

If the contents of `My` have changed -- you added an item or removed one -- of course the control has no way of knowing that, because you refused to tell it. You're just telling it there's a new list. It checks, sees it's still got the same old list, and ignores you. The `My` property of your viewmodel should be an `ObservableCollection`, because that will notify the control when you add or remove items in the collection.

The items themselves, your `MyContainer` class, must implement `INofityPropertyChanged` as well, if you want to be able to change their properties while they are displayed in the UI.

The dependency property `My` on your control must not be of type `List<T>`. It should probably be type `object`, just like [`ItemsControl.ItemsSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource). Then your control template can display it in an `ItemsControl` which knows what to do with it. If an `ObservableCollection` is bound to it as I suggested above, the `ItemsControl` will update automatically. In `OnMyProperty`, your control class can check to see if it's an observable collection as well:

```
private static void OnMyProperty(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UC control = d as UC;

    if (e.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
    {
        (e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged +=
            (s, ecc) => {
                //  Do stuff with UC and ecc.NewItems, ecc.OldItems, etc.
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After setting the value of a `DependencyProperty` it first checks if the new value is different to the old one. Only in this case the `PropertyChangedCallback` method you registered with that `DependencyProperty` is called. So the name Property**Changed** makes sense.

In your (not modified) case you not even try to change `My` (only `Date`). So there is no reason to raise the callback function.

Comment: All right, but what is the proper scenario for my case, to fire an event when My or Date changes?

Comment: For example you may call a new function `OnChange` both from `OnMyProperty` and from `Date_Click`. Maybe it is not the best way, but I don't know enough about your architecture and purpose. It depends on where and why you want to react on the changing.